# How to position yourself at the end of a Row?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am doing the search bar and I want to put the filter icon at the end of the row. I try it with `MainAxisAlignment.end` but it is not positioned.

[SearchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKkHK.png)

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Search"),
        ));
        print("Search");
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 16.0),
        height: widget.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 8.0)
            ]),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0, right: 6.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black54),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: Text("Menu"),
                    ));
                    print("Menu");
                  }),
              Text(widget.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Roboto",
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      fontSize: 16.0)),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(MdiIcons.filterOutline, color: Colors.black54)
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Remove the row widget over icon and between text widget and icon widget add expanded widget. Give it try.

Comment: If I add Expanded widget, it moves to the left but fails to position itself at the end.

Comment: Did you remove the expanded widget over icon widget? And update the code with new one in question to understand what changes you did.

Comment: Done and works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. You have to use MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween to set space between items depending on their sizes. Items will be strech to the  start and the end of the Row.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <widget>[
  Row(
     children: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black54),
           onPressed: () {
           Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
           content: Text("Menu"),));
            print("Menu");
                      }),
           Text(widget.text,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Roboto",
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          fontSize: 16.0)),]),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(MdiIcons.filterOutline, color: Colors.black54)
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```